# Match an owned variable, then get access to the variable again

Tags: rust

I want to do something along the lines of

```
enum A {
    Type1 {
        s: String
        // ... some more fields
    }
    // ... some more variants
}

impl A {
    fn consume(self) { println!("Consumed!"); }
}

fn fails() {
    let b = A::Type1 { s: String::from("Arbitrary string") };

    match b {
        A::Type1 {
            s, // (value moved here)
            // ... more fields
        } => {
            let l = s.len(); // Something using the field from the enum
            if l > 3 {
                s.into_bytes(); // do something that requires ownership of s
            } else {
                b.consume(); // Value used here after move
           }
        }
        // ... more cases
    }
}
```

However, because I destructure `b` in the match case, I don't have access to it within the body of the match.

I can reconstruct `b` from the fields, but when `b` has lots of fields this is obviously not ideal. Is there any way to get around this issue without having to rebuild `b`?

Comment: Do the destructured fields have to be owned, or are references sufficient?

Comment: They have to be owned (for example, to allow `s.into_bytes()` in the example above)

Comment: Owning the parts that come out of the destructuring means that the original object no longer exists. You can't have both.

Comment: Wouldn't `as_bytes()` suffice? If not, you'll have to clone `b`.

Comment: `into_bytes` was just an example, the actual functions being used to need ownership. I guess it makes sense that it can't be done, though it is slightly annoying. Cloning won't work for me because I can't duplicate the actual data stored. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you (almost literally) cannot have your cake and eat it too. Once you have destructured the value, the value no longer exists.

---

When non-lexical lifetimes happens, you can use a combination of NLL and match guards to prevent taking ownership in the first place:

```
#![feature(nll)]

enum A {
    Type1 { s: String },
}

impl A {
    fn consume(self) {
        println!("Consumed!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = A::Type1 {
        s: String::from("Arbitrary string"),
    };

    match b {
        A::Type1 { ref s } if s.len() <= 3 => {
            b.consume();
        }
        A::Type1 { s } => {
            s.into_bytes();
        }
    }
}
```